# Exclude cookie content from SEO (Google) - website with html/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I have a website based on html and javascript. For cookie consent it would be great to use Silktide's code - as their cookie pop up looks really nice - from https://silktide.com/tools/cookie-consent/

All works perfect, besides that the cookie consent unfortunately shows in the Google search results in the top position - before the content which is intended for Google, which is a total no-go :(

The silktide code is as follows:

---

```js
<!-- Begin Cookie Consent plugin by Silktide - http://silktide.com/cookieconsent -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.cookieconsent_options = {"message":"Vi bruger cookies for at forbedre din oplevelse, vurdere brugen af de enkelte elementer på danrengoring.dk og til at støtte markedsføringen af vores services. Ved at benytte danrengoring.dk accepterer du vores brug af cookies.","dismiss":"OK","learnMore":"Læs mere","link":"https://www.danrengoring.dk/cookiepolitik/","theme":"dark-bottom"};
</script>
 
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cookieconsent2/1.0.10/cookieconsent.min.js"></script>
<!-- End Cookie Consent plugin -->
```

---

Placement is directly before the closing  tag, however, the cookie content shows first in the Google results.

How can be indicated to Google, to show the actual site description instead of the cookie pop up content?

Thank you in advance for any hints.